# How can I sort a list of numbers numerically, starting from a specified number, in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

`my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

I want to start from number: 4

So how can I sort the list like:

`sorted_my_list = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The second list is not sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use the `index()` function on the list to find the position of the desired position/number. But I don't know of the side effects.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
starter = 4

result = my_list[my_list.index(starter):] + my_list[:my_list.index(starter)]
```

Is this something to your liking?

And if you need to sort the two section, add `sorted()` to them, altho I don't see the point of this.

```
result = sorted(my_list[my_list.index(starter):]) + sorted(my_list[:my_list.index(starter)])
```

Final edit I think. If you need to sort the list first, and then split on the `4` you would have to sort the entire list/data before hand, to get the split down the list to be correct. Otherwise you'd end up with incorrect orders if the numbers were un-sorted before the split (`my_list = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7]` for instance)

```
my_list = sorted([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
starter = 4

result = my_list[my_list.index(starter):] + my_list[:my_list.index(starter)]
```

Comment: dont think that sorts it, just splits it aand mixes it

Comment: @E.Serra Yea I added the sort at the end, forgot to put it in there.

Comment: @js-on You sure? I'm gettnig `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3]`. Which seams to match.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, as to why you want to do something like this...

Comment: @E.Serra I have **no** idea haha. But thought it was a good mental break from work trying to solve it with as little readable code as possible.